# How to remove Continuity Camera for deleted iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera, continuity

Recently, I set up an iPhone 12 Pro, which I decided not to keep [and deleted its data](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351) following Apple's advice. However, in web conferences, I can still select this camera and it even shows a battery indicator in the Mac control center despite not being linked to my iCloud Account anymore and being turned off and at an entirely different location. Of course, the camera only displays as a black frame when selected.

How to get rid of the choice option in browsers for this non-existing camera?

Comment: Try rebooting your Mac. After that, sign out of iCloud and back in.

Comment: @Allan Rebooting was enough. Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead and write up an answer and I’ll send another up vote your way

Comment: @Allan you came up with the solution, so I would feel bad about this; please post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reboot should fix this.  Failing that, manually signing out of iCloud and back in on your devices should force everything to re-authenticate cleanly.